# FFMPEG command to make timelapse from photos doesn't work with %d

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

so I am starting to go insane.
Last hour or so I tried to make a timelapse video from a series of photos, in attached image you can see the ls output of directory, the error I get, and the command I used.
[image]

```
Could find no file with path '%4d.JPG' and index in the range 0-4
%4d.JPG: No such file or directory

./ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 25 -i %4d.JPG -start_number 6646 timelapse.mp4
```

The image names goes from 6646.jpg to 13289.jpg (ls printed it in weird way)

I also tried to use '%d.jpg', '%*.jpg' instead of '%4d.jpg'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're specifying the start number for the input, it goes before `-i` of the input it applies to. Also, since there's no zero-padding, it's simply `%d`. So,

```
./ffmpeg -f image2 -start_number 6646 -framerate 25 -i %d.jpg timelapse.mp4
```

Comment: Such a small mistake, now it works thank you!